# Can I atomically increment a column value in BigTable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Does BigTable support atomic increment operations similar to `INCR` in Redis?

There is this function in the Golang library for BT - https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#ReadModifyWrite.Increment. However, I can see a situation where two instances of an app try to increment at the same time, but it's only incremented once due to a race condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bigtable operations are atomic at a row level - you won't encounter a race condition with this API call.

Comment: Thank you. With the Increment function in the library, isn't the increment happening client-side rather than server-side? So, if two clients incremented at the same time, could they end up writing the same number to BigTable in their own atomic operations?

Comment: The function happens on the server-side.

Comment: note that `ReadModifyWrite` replicates the function of a sequence in an RDBMS.